# Why isn't blob initalized?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this part of code which is supposed to create File from Buffer.

```
    const { buffer } = downloadResult;
    logger.info(buffer);
    const blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: 'image/png' });
    logger.info('fil1', blob);

    const file = new File([blob], fileName);
    logger.info('fil2', file);

    result.image = file;
    logger.info(result.image);
```

For some reason `blob` and `file` constants are empty. This is logger output:

```
20-09-2023 16:30:03:303 info: <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 02 00 00 00 02 00 08 06 00 00 00 f4 78 d4 fa 00 00 00 04 73 42 49 54 08 08 08 08 7c 08 64 88 00 ... 21314 more bytes>
20-09-2023 16:30:03:303 info: object
20-09-2023 16:30:03:303 info: fil1
20-09-2023 16:30:03:303 info: fil2
20-09-2023 16:30:03:303 info: PersistentFile {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  lastModifiedDate: null,
  filepath: undefined,
  newFilename: undefined,
  originalFilename: undefined,
  mimetype: undefined,
  hashAlgorithm: undefined,
  size: 0,
  _writeStream: null,
  hash: null,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `logger.info` support multiple arguments?

Comment: Consider `logger.info({blob})`

Comment: Yep, that's right. I used it as `console.log`. But the file still isn't initialized correctly. Why is size 0?

Comment: Maybe buffer is empty

Comment: Output of `blob` is `Blob { size: 21364, type: 'image/png' }` so I don't think it is?